# Reading data from dataGridView instead of a csv file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csv, datagridview

I have written a C# code to read data from a `csv` file. The data is in the form say:

```
2,3,4,5,6
4,2,4,5,6
4,5,6,3,2
5,3,5,6,3
```

The code to read it is:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("Data.csv");
var numbers = ProcessRawNumbers(lines);
```

The function `ProcessRawNumbers` is as follows:

```
private static List<List<double>> ProcessRawNumbers(IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        var numbers = new List<List<double>>();
        /*System.Threading.Tasks.*/
        Parallel.ForEach(lines, line =>
        {
            lock (numbers)
            {
                numbers.Add(ProcessLine(line));
            }
        });
        return numbers;
    }

private static List<double> ProcessLine(string line)
    {
        var list = new List<double>();
        foreach (var s in line.Split(Separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            double i;
            if (Double.TryParse(s, out i))
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I would like to do the same with `DataGridView`. How can this be achieved?

In `DataGridView` I give input as follows:

[image]

Also, is it possible to have the number of columns change dynamically?

Comment: How the grid is populated? Is it bound to a data source?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn, The list is populated manually.

Answer (score 0):

Data entered in a `DataGridView` is stored in its rows and cells. To exctract the data, you have to manually iterate over the rows and cell:

```
public List<string[]> ExtractGridData(DataGridView grid)
{
    int numCols = grid.Columns.Count;
    List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow) // skip the new row
            continue;
        string[] cellsData = new string[numCols];
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            if (cell.Value != null)
                cellsData[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value.ToString();
        list.Add(cellsData);
    }

    return list;
}
```

If you want to change the columns dynamically, you can access the [`Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns.aspx) property of the grid. For example, to add a column you can write:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("NewColumn", "New Column");
```

Also note that using `Parallel.ForEach` in your scenario has no advantage, because you have to process the data sequentially, and by using `lock` statement, you forced the sequential processing. So there is no parallel proccessing.

Comment: :Where do we get the "grid" variable from? Its passed as the argument to the ExtractGridData function.

Comment: @user1645333 It is your grid! The `DataGridView` you dropped in your form. By default it is named `dataGridView1`.

Comment: While calling this ExtractGridData(), what parameter are we supposed to pass to it?

Comment: @user1645333 Whatever you think you require! For me the obvious parameter was the grid to operate on.